# Could not access pidfile for Cassandra

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I were working with cassandra with no problem last hour ,but now I can't access to cassandra when I ran `cqlsh` it gave me this:

```
Connection error: Could not connect to localhost:9160
```

So I tried this:

```
sudo service cassandra status
```

And it gave me this:

> xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -
>   XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k
>
> - could not access pidfile for Cassandra

what can I do to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Also check out : http://askubuntu.com/questions/435749/cant-start-an-application-as-service-but-running-as-standalone-process-simply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may forgot stop the cassandra before delete it.

You must remove the cassandra by `purge` command and install it again.

Also check your java version that compatible with pre-requirements of the cassandra.(like cassandra 2.* needs java oracle 7.0)

Answer (score 3):

The pid file is located at `/var/run/cassandra.pid`. Check that it exists and that the root user has read/write permissions to it. Also make sure that root has rwx permissions to `/var/run`.

As for your connection refused error, it is most likely caused by cassandra not running. Check the log files in `/var/log/cassandra/*` for any exceptions.

Comment: PID may also be at `/var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pid` too

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra must have a pid to sacrifice to the gods.

I've had to trick cassandra into actually restarting.   It seems that the the restart won't continue past the failed 'stop' action if the pid isn't really there.   So I spoofed the pid file with another valid pid.  In my case I had a `tail -f` running against `/var/log/cassandra/*.log`.

I found the pid with

```
ps aux | grep tail
```

and placed that pid into the `/var/run/cassandra.pid` file.  This allowed the

```
service cassandra restart
```

to kill a process and move on to the restart.

Very ugly.  The cassandra init scripts need some work.

Answer (score 2):

I've this problem many times and I always solved it with:

sudo chown -R cassandra /var/lib/cassandra

sudo chown -R cassandra /var/log/cassandra

This on Ubuntu server 14.04 and Debian Wheezy.

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. I was doing some testing, and when I abruptly shut down the system and rebooted, I got this error when I tried checking Cassandra's status.

The pid file has the process ID of Cassandra's service that was running before shut down. This happens when Cassandra is not stopped properly.
So, I force killed the zombie process this way and started cassandra again.

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep cassandra | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}`
service cassandra start
```

Hope its helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Check out whether an ERROR occurred in /var/log/cassandra/(system.log), there must be some if you see `could not access pidfile for Cassandra`