# Fresh Cassandra installation on ubuntu trusty machine

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra

I'm trying to install Cassandra 3.4 on 64 bit ubuntu 14.04.
I followed the DataStax instructions

- [Java installation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/install/installOpenJdkDeb.html)
- [Cassandra installation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/install/installDeb.html)

Everything seems to be going alright, but when checking if cassandra is up with `nodetool status` I get:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ nodetool status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.
```

Is there something missing in the instruction?

Comment: check `sudo service cassandra status`

Comment: @Undefined_variable I get `could not access pidfile for Cassandra`

Comment: There is issue with cassandra installation.http://askubuntu.com/questions/435749/cant-start-an-application-as-service-but-running-as-standalone-process-simply  AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873573/could-not-access-pidfile-for-cassandra

Comment: @Undefined_variable sorry to bother you but I tried both removing the folder and giving the permission and still get the error. Could not access pidfile. Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check log files to find the errors.

use

`sudo find / -name "cassandra.log"`  and `sudo find / -name "system.log"`

to find what errors are mentioned there.

Then use `sudo service cassandra restart`

Edit : 
Since, cassandra.log doesn't exists, I have to assume, cassandra never got initialized.

That is why it says "Directory /var/lib/cassandra/data doesn't exist"

Lets take it step by step

1. do `sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/cassandra`
2. do `sudo mkdir /var/lib/cassandra/data /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog`
3. do `chown cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra/data`
4. do `chown cassandra:cassandra /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog`

And install Oracle jdk 1.8 instead of using openjdk.
Then restart the service.

Comment: The first command doesn't find anything the second does, and there are only warnings in the [system.log](https://gist.github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/e3688e55d8846392d350d77bfe9030ec) file. But I'm not a Linux person maybe you can see something I can't.